# Conditional template logic Vuejs

Tags: templates, logic, vue.js, vuejs2

```
    <template>
    <div>
     <div v-if="context=='home'"  v-for="item in filteredItems"  @mouseover="activate" @mouseout="deactivate" @click="openlink" class="item" :data-link="item.link" v-bind:class="item.class">

     <div v-else  v-for="item in filteredItems"  @mouseover="activate" @mouseout="deactivate" @click="openlink" :data-link="item.link">
```

I have a vuejs component, in the template I want to swap out the **v-bind:class="item.class"** and only add it if the context is home.

```
  <work context="home"></work>
```

The context is passed in via a prop.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:class="{'class_name': 'your_condition'}"
```

So in your case

```
:class="{'class_name': context === 'home'}"
```

and make sure the value of context is in lowercase to make it work. or use toLowerCase() function on the context variable.

```
:class="{'class_name': context.toLowerCase() === 'home'}"
```

**[UPDATED]**
 You can create a method like below to get this working. I created a jsBin with following method. check it out here  [substitute class name](https://jsbin.com/zulenilawa/edit?html,js,output)

```
getClass: function() {
  return this.context === 'home' ? this.item.class : '';
}
```

Comment: one more thing : use a default value for your context prop or check if context variable holds a string value to call toLowerCase() on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is close but I want to substitute in the value and using :class="{'item.class': context != 'home'} makes gives <div class="item.class">

Comment: yeah because you have  made item.class as a string. remove single quotes around from item.class

Comment: Without the quotes I get an error - avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "class" in expression :class="{item.class: context != 'home'}" it seems like it needs escaped in some way?

Comment: I have updated the answer. But not sure if this is the best way to do it. But it works !